# Update .NET web service to use TLS 1.2

Tags: c#, .net, tls1.2

I need to use TLS 1.2 to connect from my .NET web service to another that is going to force TLS 1.2.  I found a resource that said .NET 4.6 uses TLS 1.2 by default so that sounded like the easiest solution.  I updated the .NET framework on the server and restarted.  In IIS I tried to make an application pool using .NET 4.6 but 4.0 was the only option.  Then I found something that said it would still say 4.0 because 4.6 is an "in place" update to .NET 4.0.  So I thought maybe I was done.  However on an error page that I got for unrelated reasons, it said `Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319` so it seems I have not successfully upgraded.  Any pointers on how to make sure my application pool is using .NET 4.6, or more generally how to enable TLS 1.2?

Comment: I believe TLS12 must be enabled on the server. https://support.quovadisglobal.com/kb/a433/how-to-enable-tls-1_2-on-windows-server-2008-r2.aspx

Answer (score 198, accepted):

We actually just upgraded a .NET web service to 4.6 to allow TLS 1.2.

What Artem is saying were the first steps we've done. We recompiled the framework of the web service to 4.6 and we tried change the registry key to enable TLS 1.2, although this didn't work: the connection was still in TLS 1.0. Also, we didn't want to disallow SLL 3.0, TLS 1.0 or TLS 1.1 on the machine: other web services could be using this; we rolled-back our changes on the registry.

We actually changed the Web.Config files to tell IIS: "hey, run me in 4.6 please".

Here's the changes we added in the web.config + recompilation in .NET 4.6:

```xml
<system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.6"/> <!-- Changed framework 4.0 to 4.6 -->

    <!--Added this httpRuntime -->
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6" />

    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0"/>
</system.web>
```

And the connection changed to TLS 1.2, because IIS is now running the web service in 4.6 (told explicitly) and 4.6 is using TLS 1.2 by default.

Comment: Here's the documentation we used for research: [HTTPRuntime](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2012/11/19/all-about-httpruntime-targetframework/), [RenderingCompatibility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.renderingcompatibility(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I made those changes to my web.config, rebuilt, deployed, and I'm getting `System.Net.WebException: The request failed with an empty response.`  I don't know if it's from my end or a problem on the other side.  Any idea how to verify that I'm using TLS 1.2?

Comment: You could use a network protocol analyser, like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to verify the status of your connection.

Comment: I figured it out - I wasn't requesting HTTPS.  After I fixed that, it worked.

Comment: @EtienneFaucher - I am using .Net 4.5. So i make the change change in code like : SecurityProtocol = TLS | TLS1 | TLS2 or SecurityProtocol = TLS2 ?? which one is correct to make it TLS compliant.

Comment: @SunilA Both should be ok. You are accepting TLS 1.2 in both cases. In the second case, it should not accept TLS 1.0/TLS1.1 as protocol for your connections. In our case, we didn't change any code; we only changed the application framework.

Comment: Changing compilation to 4.6 and adding the httpRuntime 4.6 was enough in our case, thanks for the solution!

Comment: This is totally the right answer.  Just went through this recently. Here's a blog post about it: http://blog.thelevelup.com/pci-security-is-your-restaurant-ready/ and a GitHub project that does this: https://github.com/TheLevelUp/pos-tls-patcher

Comment: THANK YOU! -- In my case I had two programs side by side, both  being compiled with and theoretically using version 4.6, and one worked while the other one failed.  I had the epiphany that one was a web site using old web technologies and thus may be using an older version by default, I found this answer and VOILA.  Thanks for including the other ways to select the framework -- peace of mind since I'm rendering with 3.5!

Comment: All these configs were available in my project config file and it used to tls as a default version but I want to use tls12. Then I added System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12; so it forces the service to use tls12 version at the end.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls

Comment: Above URL by spikej => "Transport Layer Security (TLS) best practices with the .NET Framework"

Comment: I logged in just to upvote @user24601 - the link and suggestion to use the  TLS Patcher was the answer for me - forget trying to configure your registry manually.  Install this and it does the trick!  Thanks - maybe my hair will grow back now.

Comment: I feel obligated to point out that the best solution is to target .NET 4.7 — if 4.7 is supported on your particular platform and upgrading .NET is a real option.

Comment: You saved my day! Upgrading target to .NET 4.7 solved it. Thanks

Comment: PowerBI Embeded requires TLS 1.2 now - the above solution worked for me to force a 4.5 runtime to a 4.6 runtime.  I had to cross the 4.6 runtime level to get the TLS 1.2 defaults to work where I needed them to.

Comment: +1 but just needed to add that I had to upgrade to 4.8 to make my (4.6) app be able to use integration NuGet packages with third-party servers.

Comment: How would I do this for a .Net console app, not an IIS/web app?

Comment: You should go ahead and disallow SSL3.0 and TLS1.0. Yes, it's possible something is still using one of those protocols, but if so **that's a big deal** that warrants urgent attention to remedy the situation. Note I did not say to disable TLS1.1 yet. It's not great, but it's not (yet) at the importance of the others.

Answer (score 171):

Add the following code before you instantiate your web service client:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Or for backward compatibility with TLS 1.1 and prior:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Comment: Yeah I'm already doing that, but the error message still indicates .NET 4.0.

Comment: That is your CLR version.  The .Net CLR has two versions, 2.0 and 4.0.  In IIS you specify the CLR version, not the Framework version.  IIS won't tell you .Net 4.6 because it doesn't care about that.  If you compiled using 4.6, then you are using 4.6.

Comment: TLS 1.2 is supported from .NET 4.5 onwards

Comment: And for VB.NET: System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = DirectCast(3072, System.Net.SecurityProtocolType)

Comment: @JohnWu: I believe if we write this command in a main program of a project then all web request withing same exe will use the specified protocol. Correct me if it is the otherwise.

Comment: @Itz.Irshad The protocol is negotiated. The setting enables it.

Comment: @JohnWu: Consider the specified protocol is enabled on server. The client used a winform application to download data after specifying the protocol as suggested. Then every web request will use the same protocol. Right ?

Comment: In this case, |= is superior to just =. They're binary flags, don't overwrite everything else unnecessarily.

Comment: @JohnWu - please note Izzy's comment above. Your code tells .NET to explicitly ONLY use TLS 1.2 when connecting to HTTPS resources. I.e. if a server only had TLS 1.1, your code would stop it from connecting since it's only using TLS 1.2. You should use |= to tell your code "try to use TLS 1.2 as an option too" when the client and server negotiate which protocol to use.

Comment: This is the solution when using the stock `System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient` and the mail server requires TLS1.2.  You need to tell the `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol` to use `Tls12`.

Comment: When this is done within a web service, will it only influence the requests that service makes as a client to other services, or will it also influence the requests that service receives from other clients?

Comment: +1 But can anyone explain why this is necessary when targeting .NET Framework 4.8? Why is the newer protocol not the default?

Comment: if I'm using a windows application and I need to forcefully set the Tls12 protocol for mail sending, where can I add this below code?
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

Answer (score 42):

if you're using .Net earlier than 4.5 you wont have Tls12 in the enum so state is explicitly mentioned [here](https://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2016/04/tsl-1-2-and-net-support/)

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
```

Comment: Thank you. This helped me out. For anyone researching I was attempting to create a new folder in AzureFileStorage: fileDirectory.CreateIfNotExists(); The fileDirectory is a CloudFileDirectory object. I simply placed  ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072; before that and it worked like a charm. Thanks again.

Comment: That means .Net 4.5 on the machine, not that your application targeted compilation for 4.5. It's the operating system that supports TLS 1.2, but the application still has to allow it to be used through the SecurityProtocol setting.

Answer (score 23):

Three steps needed:

1. Explicitly mark SSL2.0, TLS1.0, TLS1.1 as forbidden on your server machine, by adding `Enabled=0` and `DisabledByDefault=1` to your registry (the full path is `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols`). See screen for details
   [image: registry]
2. Explicitly enable `TLS1.2` by following the steps from 1. Just use `Enabled=1` and `DisabledByDefault=0` respectively.

NOTE: verify server version: `Windows Server 2003` does not support the `TLS 1.2` protocol

3. Enable `TLS1.2` only on app level, like @John Wu suggested above.

   `System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;`

Hope this guide helps.

**UPDATE**
As @Subbu mentioned: [Official guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/dn786418(v=ws.11)#BKMK_SchannelTR_TLS12)

Comment: Official reference - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn786418(v=ws.11).aspx#BKMK_SchannelTR_TLS12

Comment: Hi @Artem after adding the tls do i need to restart the server?

Comment: @Simba you probably solved this, but doing this just now I did NOT need to restart the server.

Comment: Nothing worked but this. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

For me below worked:

**Step 1:** Downloaded and installed the web Installer exe from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48137  on the application server. Rebooted the application server after installation was completed.

**Step 2:** Added below changes in the **web.config**

```
<system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.6"/> <!-- Changed framework 4.0 to 4.6 -->
    <!--Added this httpRuntime -->
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6" />
</system.web>
```

**Step 3:** After completing step 1 and 2, it gave an error, "***WebForms UnobtrusiveValidationMode requires a ScriptResourceMapping for 'jquery'. Please add a ScriptResourceMapping named jquery(case-sensitive)***" and to resolve this error, I added below key in **appsettings** in my **web.config** file

```
<appSettings>
      <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
</appSettings>
```

Comment: Adding the httpRuntime target framework worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Updating the server with .Net 4.6 or later will use TLS 1.2.

Found this out through troubleshooting some failed email issues with one of our console applications.

The server only had .Net 4.5 installed, and emails were failing.

On my local workstation, i had .Net 4.6, and when running the console app, the emails weren't failing.

So we moved the console app to a server that had .Net 4.6, didn't change anything else, and the emails were working again.

Comment: Is this different from the accepted answer?

Comment: Yes it is, because we didn't have to make any code changes, or any changes to the web.config file, no need to recompile anything.  But thanks for checking just in case. 

Answer (score 0):

**PowerBI Embedded requires TLS 1.2.**

The answer above by ***Etienne Faucher*** is your solution.
quick link to above answer... [quick link to above answer...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45442874)
( https://stackoverflow.com/a/45442874 )

PowerBI Requires TLS 1.2 June 2020 - [This Is your Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45442874) - Consider Forcing your IIS runtime to get up to 4.6 to force the default TLS 1.2 behavior you are looking for from the framework.  The above answer gives you a config change only solution.

*Symptoms*: Forced Closed Rejected TCP/IP Connection to Microsoft PowerBI Embedded that just shows up all of a sudden across your systems.

These PowerBI Calls just stop working with a Hard TCP/IP Close error like a firewall would block a connection.  Usually the auth steps work - it is when you hit the service for specific workspace and report id's that it fails.

[This is the 2020 note from Microsoft PowerBI about TLS 1.2 required](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/power-bi-support-for-transportlayer-security/)

PowerBIClient

*methods that show this problem*

GetReportsInGroupAsync  GetReportsInGroupAsAdminAsync GetReportsAsync GetReportsAsAdminAsync Microsoft.PowerBI.Api
HttpClientHandler Force TLS 1.1 TLS 1.2

Search Error Terms to help people find this:
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request
System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the Server will needed Cyphers TLS moderns and the OS client havent this Cyphers, in this case the command "ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;" doesnt work... here only solution was change server  OS (Win2021 to Win2019)