# How to tick "TLS 1.2"(Internet Option > Advanced setting > Security> TLS 1.2) using C#

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control, internet-explorer-10, tls1.2

Our application using  Webbrowser control / Internet Explorer to display some web pages. We need to enable TLS 1.2(Internet Options->Advanced->Security->Use TLS 1.2) to display these web pages. Now we are facing some issues in Win 8 when disabling (by default disabled) TLS 1.2 option. So we need to check whether it is ticked and if not we need to tick it programmatically in C#. We have tried by setting registry value but it doesn’t’ help.
Is there any way to tick "Internet Options->Advanced->Security->Use TLS 1.2" programmatically.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update .NET web service to use TLS 1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45382254/update-net-web-service-to-use-tls-1-2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [Registry.SetValue Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registry.setvalue?view=netframework-4.8) to set change the registry and enable TLS 1.2.

Code as below (need to add the "using Microsoft.Win32;" reference):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // The name of the key must include a valid root.
    const string userRoot = @"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings";
    const string subkey = "SecureProtocols";

    //get the registry value.
    string result = (Registry.GetValue(userRoot, subkey, "Return this default if NoSuchName does not exist")).ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(result);

    //Enable TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.2 
    Registry.SetValue(userRoot, subkey, 2176);

    Console.WriteLine("OK");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

More details about the registry key value, please refer to [this article](https://getadmx.com/?Category=InternetExplorer&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.InternetExplorer::Advanced_SetWinInetProtocols).