# TLS 1.2 and an existing connection was forcibly closed by remote host

Tags: .net, tls1.2

I am trying to send an HTTP POST to the address https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken?grant_type=.... using a HttpClient class from C#. When I run the code on my local Win10, or when I run it on Windows Server 2016, it works fine.

However, when I run it from Windows Server 2008 R2, I am getting the error

> An existing connection was forcibly closed by remote host.

Now, I know that LinkedIn does support only TLS 1.2 since a while. I tried to explicitly set TLS in my code:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
```

Still the same error on Win2008R2.
I tried targeting .Net Framework 4.6.1, 4.7.1, 4.7.2, to no avail.

What could be the problem?

I saw already threads on SO like these: [Twitter API responds with 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57271345/twitter-api-responds-with-an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-rem)

Does not work however for me.