# What version TLS does System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient support?

Tags: .net, ssl, tls1.2, system.net.mail

I'm sending emails using System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient. It has an EnableSsl property that seems to work most of the time, but now one user claims that his email provider will only accept connections with minimum TLS 1.2 and that he is trying to connect using TLS 1.1.

What versions of TLS can System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient use?

Comment: Is it using at least version 4.5 of the .NET Framework? Also, [Update .NET web service to use TLS 1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45382254/1115360).

Comment: Thanks! It's using .NET Framework version 4.6.2. I'll ask the user to try making the changes to his web.config suggested in your link and see if that helps.