# AgileDotNet obfuscator messes up httpClient.PostAsync

Tags: c#, obfuscation

I noticed that an app obfuscated with AgileDotNet is unable to send `httpClient.PostAsync` requsts. I trimmed the problem down to 20 lines of code so everyone can try it.

```
  internal class Program
  {
    public static void Main(string[] args){
      Send("lala", "https://url");
      Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static async Task<string> Send(string jsonString, string url){

      using (var client = new HttpClient()){

        StringContent stringContent = new StringContent(jsonString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var result = await client.PostAsync(url, stringContent);

        Console.WriteLine(result.StatusCode);
        if (result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK){
          string response = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
          Console.WriteLine(response);
          return response;

        }else{
          string response = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
          Console.WriteLine(response);
          return response;
        }
      }

    }
  }
```

The code below will send a Post request if it is not obfucated. If AgileDotNet is used, it will never send a request. Moreover, error is completely silent as is is not shown in Event Viever nor in the console.

Has anyone experienced this? Any known workarounds? I am using AgileDotNet 6.6.0.11

Update: when changing Main's return type to `async Task` and calling `await Send` I recieved an error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext& context)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at ohM=.oRM=.<Send>d__1.MoveNext() in C:\Users\User\source\repos\PostAsyncTests\PostAsyncTests\Program.cs:line 24
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at ohM=.oRM=.<Main>d__0.MoveNext() in C:\Users\User\source\repos\PostAsyncTests\PostAsyncTests\Program.cs:line 14
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at ohM=.oRM=.pRM=(String[] args)
```

Apparently, establishing SSL connection causes problems.

agile project .cls file in question:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<AgileDotNet Version="6.6.0.11">
  <AssemblyList>
    <Assembly Path="PostAsyncTests.exe" Secure="true" Obfuscation="true" FlowObfuscation="true" MethodCallObfuscation="true" ILMerge="none" />
  </AssemblyList>
  <Settings>
    <General OutputDirectory="Secured" SignatureFile="" PfxPassword="" FilePathMode="relativepath" GenerateDebugInfo="True" SdkPath="" />
    <Obfuscation ObfuscationMapFile="ObfuscationMap" RenamingScheme="printablechars" CrossAssemblyObfuscation="true" ExcludeXamlTypes="false" ControlFlowObfuscation="basic" PredefindSymbolNamesFilePath="" RenameMethodParameters="False">
      <RenamingExclusions />
      <AssemblyLoadPaths />
    </Obfuscation>
    <Secure SecureUserStrings="true" EncryptManagedResources="true" RedistName="AgileDotNetRT" RedistName64="AgileDotNetRT64" DisableRuntimeEmbedding="False" AntiDebuggerDetection="False" SkipSmallMethods="False" />
    <Tracking ConfigureErrorReporting="false" ProductName="PostAsyncTests" ProductVersion="1.0.0.0" CompanyName="SecureTeam Software Ltd." />
    <CodeVirtualization PerformCodeVirtualization="false" RedistName="AgileDotNet.VMRuntime" />
    <LicenseFeatures />
  </Settings>
  <Licensing>
    <Licenses />
  </Licensing>
</AgileDotNet>
```

Comment: Does it happen with `async woid Main` and `await Send()`?

Comment: It does, But this time, I recieve an error. See update. Apparently, establishing SSL connection causes problems.

Comment: Are you compatible with the server in terms of the TLS version? https://stackoverflow.com/a/45383835/11683