# .Net 4.8 is not automatically working with TLS1.2 Azure storage

Tags: c#, azure-storage, tls1.2, .net-4.8

I have an old C# win forms project (.Net 4) working with azure storage. I recently updated the project to .Net 4.8 (Visual Studio 2015...) and the azure storage to V2 using TLS1.2.
Unfortunately I still have to define the SecurityProtocol to get my blobs uploaded (otherwise I'll get error 400).

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

This seems to be bad practice and I wonder why it is not working with .Net 4.8 without specifying the SecurityProtocol. Documentations state that it should be working with .Net >4.6.
I already checked my registry and it says .Net 4.8 is installed (value of release 528372). Is that anyhow depended on my azure libraries? I still use the library Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage; (Update is in progress...)

Any hints on that?

EDIT 1:
Windows version is 10 and an official supported version.
Visual Studio 2015 was originally used for the project. So I used it again (and due to the IS LE used...).
It is a WinForms desktop application running locally and not at any server.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update .NET web service to use TLS 1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45382254/update-net-web-service-to-use-tls-1-2)

Comment: You need to add `<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.8" />` or `<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.8.1" />` to your config. Also TLS1.2 needs to be available on the server, so you need the latest updates, and in the case of Server 2012 you need to change the registry

Comment: What's the version of Windows? TLS encryption is provided by the OS. All supported Windows versions use TLS 1.2. Are you using an unsupported Windows version? Is that why you use the unsupported VS 2015?

Comment: Is this actually a WinForms app? -- Setting the `SecurityProtocol` is not *bad practice*, per se. But it shouldn't be needed anymore. What is the System version? Is it maybe Windows 7, given that you have an old version of VS (you should update it, btw) and you're not targeting v.4.8.1? -- Get [IIS Crypto](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto) (free software) and for a quick view of what's enabled in the System -- Why did you check the Registry, when you have a Project that targets .NET Fx 4.8? It's clearly installed. It's installed anyway, if you have at least Windows 10 there

Comment: Setting `SecurityProtocol` *is* a bad practice because it *prevents* the use of better algorithms like TLS 1.3 on Windows 11 or Windows Server 2022. All supported Windows versions support TLS 1.2.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It's not when it's the only way to make your app work. If you're referring to services that are distributed on servers, that's extremely bad (practice?). But why would anyone do that? If it's a desktop application, it's one of the things you have to test and force it if/when needed. Otherwise, you'd have to explain to your users why your app is the only one that doesn't work. Fortunately, this can be considered something that belongs to the past. Unless you need to support older Systems

Comment: @Jimi It doesn't do what you think it does. In 4.6 and up, If TLS 1.2 is disabled then setting `SecurityProtocol` doesn't help. And if TLS 1.1 is still enabled then clearly the user has decided to take that risk. And if TLS 1.3 is enabled then it won't be used.

Comment: `So I used it again` don't use it. That version never supported .NET Framework 4.8 and the changes it brings to libraries, designer features etc. The Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition is free unless you're in a "big" company (>250 PCs or over $1M per year). VS 2022 contains many Azure extensions that allow you to work with your Azure resources directly and more importantly, verify that you *can* connect

Comment: What's the actual exception you get if you *remove* the hard-coded TLS version? Post the full exception text. The error may have nothing to do with TLS but an intermediate corporate proxy

Comment: @Charlieface What users are you talking about? Office / home users? Have these *made a choice* about the TLS Protocol, when barely can remember which keys need to be pressed to *make the text bold*? You're talking about sys admins. In relation to desktop apps (since the OP refers to a WinForms app, even though you removed the tag), as stated: *it's one of the things you have to test and force it if/when needed* <- you **test it**, then your code makes a decision. As all other devs (and their apps) do, in these scenarios. Or explain that *my app doesn't work because it follows best practices *

Comment: @Jimi Again: if TLS 1.2 is disabled in the registry (or not installed if on a non-updated system) then anything you do will not make it available. There is nothing to test or set, it just doesn't work. If TLS 1.2 *is* enabled then setting it makes no difference, it will be used anyway, and all that does is disable *newer* versions of TLS.

Comment: @Jimi the way TLS 1.2 and SecurityProtocol behave is well documented in [learn.microsoft.com docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls) docs, with published patches, guides and KB articles for older systems, since 2015 if not earlier. The big switch to TLS 1.2 happened in 2016. There's nothing to test here. Without the *actual* error we need to guess what the OP's problem actually is. If they use 4.8 on Windows 10 without legacy switches, then the problem is something else. Perhaps bad certificates, Fiddler or a corporate proxy, or just networking

Comment: @becky Try to isolate the problem. Try to connect to Azure in a *new*, clean application. Does that work? If  not, what's the *actual* error? Even better, install VS 2022 Community and use the [Connected Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/azure/overview-connected-services?view=vs-2022) tooling to connect to Azure Storage. If the tooling fails, the problem isn't in your project

Comment: I would think a Wireshark trace would be best to find out what's really happening here. What does the Server Hello and Client Hello look like?

Comment: @becky Even without VS 2022, you can use the Azure CLI commands to connect and test various features. Do these work?

Comment: I switched to VS 2019 which I already have in use. It told me that a subclass couln't be loaded. Fixed that and everything is working now. Strange VS2015 behaviour. And yes VS2022 is on my agenda.

Comment: @Charlieface You probably haven't read my first comment entirely: *Fortunately, this can be considered something that belongs to the past*. Not long ago, but still today, in some cases, if you have support older Systems - hence you need to target older versions of the Framework, you **had to** force the Protocol version. Of course, if it's not available, you cannot *enable* anything; what point is that? Again, I'm talking about desktop apps, not server stuff. That's why I asked the OP about the System version in use and hinted whether they were sure about the targeted .NET version

Answer (score 0):

Adding `<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.8" />`to the Web.config file

```
<system.web>

    <!--Added this httpRuntime -->
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.8" />

</system.web>
```

Comment: This will have no effect if the Windows version doesn't support TLS 1.2

Comment: Duplicate link says the same.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was a reference to an old class project still using .Net 4.0 (inside the same project map). Usually Visual Studio informes me about this, but not now. Updated the project to 4.8 and everything works fine. I really don't understand why and why I got no error or warning. Makes no sense for me. But somehow this was the blocker for the TLS.